# Problem with the counter of collisions

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, collision-detection, counter

Here is my code :

```
-(void)detectCollision{

  imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);


    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame,centre.frame)){


    label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
  ++count;
}
```

I have a CADisplayLink(60fps) on detectCollision.
I want to increment "count" of one every time "imageView" collide with "centre", but my problem is that count increment too fast, every time there is a collision it increment of near 100 or 200, I don't know why. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because everytime the frames start intersecting in,

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame,centre.frame))
```

your condition will be true until the frames separate and the count increases over 100 in the CADisplayLink

so you can use a BOOL and set it to true when the frames first intersects. then check whether they are separate and make the BOOL back to false.

initialize `BOOL intersectFlag` to false in init. I assume that the frames wont intersect initially.

```
-(void)detectCollision
{ 
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);

    if(!intersectFlag)
    {    
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame,centre.frame))    
        {
            intersectFlag = YES;         
            label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
            ++count;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(!CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame,centre.frame))
        {
            intersectFlag = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't work, the counter increase very fast until imageView doesn't touch centre

Comment: did you initialize intersectFlag to NO in init

Comment: no but I never use BOOL, how can I initialize intersectFlag to NO in init

Comment: declare BOOL intersectFlag; in *.h file. and initialize intersectFlag = NO; in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

to find out collision u should use with bounds not frame

bounds - size inside of object

frame - offset from superview x,y + size(bounds)

here i assume u are in portrait mode

```
-(void)detectCollision{

        if(CGRectContainsPoint( imageView.bounds, CGPointMake(160, 240)) ){


                label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];

                ++count;

        }


    }
```